# Cloud environment on Windows Azure platform

Tags: azure, cloud

I've got 6 web sites, 2 databases and 1 cloud environment setup on my account

I used the cloud to run some tasks via Windows Task Manager, everything was installed on my D drive but between last week and today the 8 of March my folder containing the "exe" to run as been removed.
Also I've installed SVN tortoise to get the files deployed and it not installed anymore

I wonder if somebody has a clue about my problem

Best Regards

Franck merlin

Comment: Where did you have all those files? The cloud service? When a new instance is created within Windows Azure (because of scaling up, hardware problem, or server updates) the system uses the original package to recreate the instance, deleting anything that was installed after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Cloud Services (web/worker roles), these are *stateless* virtual machines. That is: Windows Azure provides the operating system, then brings your deployment package into the environment after bootup. Every single virtual machine instance booted this way starts from a clean OS image, along with the exact same set of code bits from you.

Should you RDP into the box and manually install anything, anything you install is going to be temporary at best. Your stuff will likely survive reboots. However, if the OS needs updating (especially the underlying host OS), your changes will be lost as a fresh OS is brought up.

This is why, with Cloud Services, all customizations should be done via startup tasks or the OnStart() event. You should *never* manually install anything via RDP since:

- Your changes will be temporary
- Your changes won't propagate to additional instances; you'll be required to RDP into every single box to perform the same changes.

You may want to download the [Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) and look through some of the Cloud Service labs to get a better feel for startup tasks.

Comment: Didn't know the training kit existed. Thanks for that one

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what David said, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/10/05/windows-azure-disk-partition-preservation.aspx for the scenarios where the different drives will be destroyed.

Also take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx which points you to the RSS feed and MSDN article where you can see that a new OS is currently being deployed.